# Reference Request: Physics 1 for people who already know the math

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, resource-recommendations, education

I'm a Statistics undergraduate student and, this semester, I took a Physics 1 (Mechanics) class. The physics in this class is really just high-school physics but with basic Calculus and some Linear Algebra. You get to ignore things like friction, air resistance, assume objects to be particles, all this kind of stuff that makes things simpler.

The textbook we're using in this class is Young & Freedman's *University Physics*. The problem I have with this book is that it's very slow because it's made for very young people, who are often fresh out of high school, and the authors don't assume previous knowledge of linear algebra, and only assume trivially basic knowledge of calculus.

As a consequence, the discussions and examples are unecessarily long and detailed. So **what I'm looking for** here is some material that covers Physics 1 mechanics but is focused on people who have already taken the standard calculus and linear algebra classes. And by material I mean anything really, lecture notes avaiable online, YouTube playlists, etc.

Comment: Landau and Lifshitz - Volume 1 of Course of Theoretical Physics: Mechanics -> It's a quick paced book that covers the fundamentals well if you know the mathematics.

Comment: @Qmechanic all the books referenced in the post you mentioned are graduate-level mechanics or require knowledge of freshman physics. Meanwhile, I'm looking for freshman physics material that doesn't waste a page explaining how to add vectors or how to calculate a cross product, this kind of thing. My post is not a duplicate of the post you referenced.

Comment: Be advised that res. recom. are restricted on Phys.SE.